# Hide comment after deleting

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

I have tride to add function hide after deleting the comment. but it hide all comments. but i need to hide just deleted comment. there is my js.

```
$('.delete_p').click(function(){
var del_id = $(this).attr('id_p');
$.ajax({
 type: 'POST',
 url: 'delete_post.php',
 data:'delete_id='+del_id,
 success: function(data){
    $('#status .holder'+del_id).fadeOut();
 }
});
});
 $( ".delete_p" ).click(function() {
 $( "#status .holder").hide("slow");
});
```

i have tride to add `this`but it doesn't helped.

```
$( "#status .holder", $(this)).hide( "slow" );
```

here is html. it is too long. there is just used for comment:

```
<div id="status">
<div class='holder' id_p='<?php echo $post_id; ?>'>
<div class='holder_half'>
<?php
$default_s_pic = "href=/default_picture.png";
echo "<div id='picture'><a href='/$poster_name'>";
if($adder_pic === ""){
echo '<img src="', $default_s_pic, '" alt="', $poster_f_name,'\'s Profile image">';
}else{
    echo '<img src="', $adder_pic, '" alt="', $poster_f_name,'\'s Profile image">';
}
echo "
</a>
</div>
<div class='ten'>
<div id='statusname'><a href='/$poster_name'>$poster_f_name</a></div>
<div class='date_time'>$data</div>
<span class='span' data-ft='{&quot;tn&quot;:&quot;K&quot;}'>
";
if($posted_place === $deleter || $poster_name === $deleter){
echo "
<button class='delete_p' id_p='". $post_id ."'>x</button>
";
?><script src="delete_post.js"></script>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: If possible, can post `html` ? Thanks

Comment: $('#' + del_id).hide("slow");

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change This code:

```
<div class='holder' id_p='<?php echo $post_id; ?>'>
```

to this:

```
<div class='holder<?php echo $post_id; ?>' id_p='<?php echo $post_id; ?>'>
```

Comment: it works really. thanks for your help. it is amaizing. thanks a lot. :) @patternprogrammer